# SupportMapFragment with ViewPager: Cannot move camera or change map settings

Tags: android, dictionary, android-viewpager, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have a problem with the `SupportMapFragment` and moving the camera to a location on the map.

```
public class MapPositionFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements LocationListener{

private GoogleMap map = null;
private Button lockButton = null;
private Location currentLocation = null;
private LocationManager locationManager = null;
private View mapView = null;

@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mapView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_route_map, container, false);

    SetUpMap(v);
    return v;
  }

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {

    if (isVisibleToUser){
        SetUpLocationService();
    }
}   

private void SetUpLockButton(){
    lockButton = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lock_screen_button);
    lockButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ToggleLockButton();
        }
    });     
}

private void ToggleLockButton(){
    BaseSwipeActivity baseActivity = (BaseSwipeActivity)getActivity();
    boolean swipeEnabled = baseActivity.TogglePaging();

    if (swipeEnabled){
        lockButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stock_lock_open);
    }
    else{
        lockButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stock_lock);
    }
}

private void SetUpLocationService(){
    boolean gpsIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean networkIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (networkIsEnabled){
        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    } else if (gpsIsEnabled){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

}

private void SetCurrentLocation(final Location location){

    if (map != null){
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
                map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
              }
        });

    }
}

private void SetUpMap(View view) {
    if (map == null){
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                map = getMap();
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
                map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
                locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
              }
        });
    }
}

@Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SetUpLockButton();
  }


public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      SetCurrentLocation(location);
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

It's  `SupportMapFragment` which is positioned inside a `ViewPager`. The map is shown, but I cannot change the map settings and i'm not able to change the camera position. I thought maybe because it's in a other thread I have to use the UI Thread, but that doesn't change anything.

So maybe someone has an idea, it would be great!

thx Manuel

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with `ViewPager`. Check your LogCat to see if you have an authorization failure, in which case your problem is that you have either the wrong API key in your manifest, or the API key is not authorized for your signing key or package name in the API Console. Here is a sample project of `SupportMapFragments` in  a `ViewPager`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Pager

Comment: there are no errors in logcat. the heading of my post was wrong, i'm able to show the map. the problem now is that i'm not able to change the camera position on the map. so my api keys should work.

Comment: See my sample code at the link for changing camera position.

Comment: yes i've seen it, and i make it like that. i also use the camerupdatefactory to set the new latlng position and zoom. after that i use the movecamera method to change the position and zoom, i also tried it with the animatecamera method. 

i stepped inside my setcurrentlocation method, and the locationmanger injects the correct location, but there is no camera change.

i tried it on my nexus 7.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem today. Here's my solution for it.

As you had:

```
// @ SetUpMap()
map = getMap();
```

Replace it with:

```
// Remeber to change the map id (R.id.map) to what you have in the layout .xml
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
```

**Seems like this solution doesn't work with Android support library 21.0.x (I have tested for .2 and .3). As this method works with older Android support libraries there might be a bug etc.**